# Display or track dirtied variables in Svelte for examination in dev tools?

Tags: javascript, svelte

I'm struggling with code executing 3,4 or 5 times when I only need it to execute once. To tame this, I need to track down what's causing each reaction. **Is there a way to have Svelte list (in the console or something similar) the variables it dirties in the order of reactivity**? I'd like to put a breakpoint on the code that's getting executed and hit Play multiple times and find out what variable is reacting that caused the line to execute.